# How do I create an Excel 365 formula to calculate the median of values across 7 consecutive rows recurring every 12th row?

Tags: arrays, repeat, median

- My hope is to provide the what I'll call the **immediate** median (for cells B5:B11 - cell B2) as well as the **cumulative** median (cells B5:B11, B17:B23 - cell B3) -- excluding blank cells.  The formula for the immediate median of one array seems straightforward, but how would I create a formula for an ever-expanding 1xn array where values occur regularly (7 successive rows) but are non-contiguous over weeks (i.e., 7 successive cells that repeat after 5 irrelevant values in between)?

Haven't tried much yet.  I'm wondering if a mod of the row number might somehow work but not sure how to create that logic -- i.e., if the mod of the row number corresponds to the desired 7 rows (across the growing array), then calculate the median across those rows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5eFx.png)  (table illustrating sample data with constraint)